# Detected DOM changes in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

it is possible to somehow detect DOM changes and trigger then some function that can manipulate with this DOM element data before and after change?

Comment: WATIR can know If element has gone to stale while it tries to interact it and it regains the element as well.

Comment: You could have Watir constantly poll the page or have it inject JavaScript into the page. The specific answer really depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let assume that I need open page and listen changes on some table element, if for example some td changes then watir SOMEHOW trigger SOME function and return changed element in this particular case table element

Comment: one of the solutions, you can add onchange event to the table and it's following elements. Then capture the element in your conchange implementation. you can do this in pure js and store the element(s). Call js function to retrieve the elements in your watir.